# What's the difference between using link and script tag to reference JavaScript source?

Tags: javascript

I've tried using both the following source-reference-lines<del>. They both compile</del>. But what is the difference?

1st method:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2nd method:

```
<link href="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

---

Note: There's also the similar *[Difference between `script` and `link as="script"` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105967/difference-between-script-and-link-as-script)* which asks about `<link href="js/script.js" as="script">`, which is different.

Comment: `link` tag is used to relate stylesheets instead of javascripts.

Comment: @epascarello it compiles if inserted into the header in an ASP.NET Web Forms page, in Visual Studio, with ReSharper, even after rebuilding. That's all I've tried.

Comment: I ran into this today too since JetBrains IntelliJ / WebSphere seems to think `script` is a possible value for `link rel=`.

Comment: I vaguely recall that it only compiled at first, of unknown (possibly buggy) reasons and then it didn't after I posted that comment (I forgot to return here and post that I guess). The IntelliSense has also often suggested things that were invalid values and this scenario may have been included in that. I haven't tried it in IntelliJ though.

Comment: Not sure why someone thought about two separate methods to import css and JS. It could simply have been <import docname="x.ss" type="css">

Comment: I know this is an old question but you can do <link> ... as="script"</link> by now so I wonder what's the difference then

Comment: but what about something like this : <link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script">

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`link` tag is used to relate stylesheets or any other linked documents instead of including javascript files.

The HTML [**Link Element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/link) `<link>` specifies relationships between the current document and other documents. Possible uses for this element include defining a relational framework for navigation and linking the document to a style sheet.

**`rel` Attribute:**

> This attribute names a relationship of the linked document to the current document. The attribute must be a space-separated list of the link types values. The most common use of this attribute is to specify a link to an external style sheet: the rel attribute is set to stylesheet, and the href attribute is set to the URL of an external style sheet to format the page. WebTV also supports the use of the value next for rel to preload the next page in a document series.

**Possible Values:**

- **alternate** - An alternate version of the document (i.e. print page, translated or mirror)
- **stylesheet** - An external style sheet for the document
- **start** - The first document in a selection
- **next** - The next document in a selection
- **prev** - The previous document in a selection
- **contents** - A table of contents for the document
- **index** - An index for the document
- **glossary** - A glossary (explanation) of words used in the document
- **copyright** - A document containing copyright information
- **chapter** - A chapter of the document
- **section** - A section of the document
- **subsection** - A subsection of the document
- **appendix**  An appendix for the document
- **help**  A help document
- **bookmark**  A related document
- **shortcut icon** A related (favorite icon) image of the document

**While** The HTML [**Script Element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) `<script>` is used to embed or reference an executable script within an HTML or XHTML document.

Comment: So can the `link`-tag only reference to CSS files or is it just everything else than .js-files?

Comment: Not only css, You can relate favorite icons, glossaries, contents etc... but not `javasctipt`

Comment: He asked about the link tage versus script tag (as I am looking for information about).  A.K. wrote about the link tag his answer but wrote nothing about script tag.

Comment: Also confirmed with W3C draft http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/links.html#linkTypes

Comment: `link` tag with `prefetch`/`preload` relationship can download JavaScript files (without executing/including them, of course).

Answer (score 5):

The second (using `link`) shouldn't work or run and is non-standard.

http://jsfiddle.net/qMKUv/

Comment: I'm not familiar with fiddle, but I'm guessing that the fact that the script does nothing when I run it, proves that it doesn't work, or am I misunderstanding your implication?

Comment: I got `<link as="script" href="http://example.com/script.js" rel="preload" />` from a page in GitHub but it works on my Chrome. Weird.

Comment: @FranklinYu I indeed saw it too. But they use `preload` here to  start downloading the script, and use `script src=""` at the end of the `body` element to load it.

Comment: @Charlie, "preload" feature seems to be [pretty new](https://www.w3.org/TR/preload/) and [not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-preload), is it? I haven't heard about this interesting feature before.

Comment: @FranklinYu I don't know how Github handles it on the backend, and if they check if my browser will accept it first, but it's a handy technique to download the script before using it. I use Firefox 46.0.1

Comment: @Charlie, I tried a GitHub webpage with Safari, which does not support the preload hint, and I still see that hint. I guess the GitHub does "check if your browser will accept it", just that browsers not supporting such feature (Firefox and Safari) would simply omit the line and fall back to legacy behavior. Note that the `link` tag does not run the script (only downloads it), and we still need a `script` tag to do so (as before), so this answer holds anyway.

Answer (score 3):

HTML is full of historical quirks, and `link` vs `script` is one of them.

Originally, `link` was used to show the relationship between the current page and another, such as the `next` page. There was no sense of including more data into the current page.

When JavaScript was developed, it included the creation of two new tags: `script` to contain the JavaScript, and `noscript`. In non-supporting browsers (or those with JavaScript turned off) the content of the `script` tag would then be ignored, and the alternative content in the `noscript` tag would be used.

For reasons best known to the developers, the `script` tag doubled up as an include via a `src` attribute, but embedded JavaScript, if any, would be ignored.

CSS didn’t come into the picture until much later, and the developers also included an embedded version in the `style` tag. However, they took a different approach for an included file, and repurposed the `link` for that.

If JavaScript were developed more recently, it’s possible that they might also have used the `link` for included files, but that wasn’t to be.

Answer (score 0):

- `<link>` for CSS
- `<script>` for JS