# concatenating several files into single file and having one link

Tags: html, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-concat

Let's say, I concatenate `file1.js`, `file2.js` and  `file3.js` into one file `filesaltogether.js` and this new file will be copied from dev to dist of the project.

Now, how should the three links to these three files; ie `<scipt src="file1.js">...<script src="file3.js">` get converted to one link to this new file `filesaltogether.js` not by hand in the `index.html` file in the dist folder of the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how should the three links to these three files; ie `<link href="file1.js">...<link href-"file3.js"` get converted to one link to this new file `filesaltogether.js`...

Firstly, `<link href="file1.js">` is not a valid way to link your JavaScript files to your html documents.

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178429/whats-the-difference-between-using-link-and-script-tag-to-reference-javascript) for more info on how the `<link>` tag is used.

The examples below show the correct syntax for linking JavaScript files to a html document:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
```

...or without the `type` attribute, as the `type` is assumed to be JavaScript if not defined in HTML5.

```html
<script src="file1.js"></script>
```

Therefore, my following answer assumes that what you really mean is how can the three `<script>` tags get converted to one `<script>` tag.

To achieve this there is a useful grunt plugin called [grunt-processhtml](http://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml)

This plugin allows you to add special comments to your html markup which then get processed by Grunt. For your requirement you would add the following comments to your source `.html` markup:

```html
<!--build:js filesaltogether.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js"></script>
<!--/build-->
```

The comment `<!--build:js filesaltogether.js-->` basically says replace all the proceeding `script` tags with one. The resultant output would be:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="filesaltogether.js"></script>
```

You can also define the `src` path inside the comment. E.g.

```html
<!--build:js path/to/file/filesaltogether.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js"></script>
<!--/build-->
```

would result in:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/file/filesaltogether.js"></script>
```

In addition to adding the special comments to your html markup you will also need to add a `processhtml` task in your `Gruntfile.js` of course.

The example below would:

1. Concatenate the three `JavaScript` files and output a file named `filesaltogether.js` to the `js` folder inside the `dist` folder
2. Replace the special comments inside the html file with a single `<script>` tag linking to the concatenated `JavaScript` file.

NOTE: You will need to edit the file paths according to your project directory setup.

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        /* CONCATENATE JAVASCRIPT*/
        concat: {
            js: {
                src: [
                    'dev/js/file1.js',
                    'dev/js/file2.js',
                    'dev/js/file3.js'
                ],
                dest: './dist/js/filesaltogether.js'
            }
        },

        /* PROCESS THE SPECIAL COMMENTS IN THE HTML */
        processhtml: {
            replaceScriptLinks: {
                files: {
                    './dist/index.html': ['./dev/index.html'] // destination : source
                }
            }
        }

    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-processhtml');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'concat:js',
        'processhtml:replaceScriptLinks'
    ]);

};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for help