# What is the difference between `script` and `link as="script"` tags?

Tags: javascript, html, head

Additionally to the standard method of loading scripts:

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

I have seen people do this:

```
<link href="js/script.js" as="script">
```

Is there any difference?

---

Note: There's a similar [*What's the difference between using link and script tag to reference JavaScript source?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178429/) question asking about `<link href="script.js" type="text/javascript" />`, which is different.

Comment: @Rustyjim I found this, too, but it is an old question that came to the, at this time, correct solution that link cannot be used to load javascript which does no longer seem to be the case

Comment: Well i also found this https://w3c.github.io/preload/#link-element-extensions maybe helpful :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If that `link` tag had `rel="preload"` (or `rel="modulepreload"`) on it, it would indicate a preload request, which would preload, but not run, the script. In contrast, `script` loads and runs the script. But without `rel`, that `link` is invalid and has no useful effect (at least in terms of the specification).

If you look up [`link`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-link-element) in the spec, you'll see `as` listed as:

> `as` — Potential destination for a preload request (for `rel="preload"` and `rel="modulepreload"`)

Following the link to [`as`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-link-as) attribute, it says:

> The `as` attribute specifies the potential destination for a preload request for the resource given by the `href` attribute. It is an enumerated attribute. Each potential destination is a keyword for this attribute, mapping to a state of the same name. The attribute must be specified on `link` elements that have a `rel` attribute that contains the `preload` keyword. It may be specified on `link` elements that have a `rel` attribute that contains the `modulepreload` keyword; in such cases it must have a value which is a script-like destination. For other `link` elements, it must not be specified.