# Django serving build with many MIME Type errors (sveltekit)

Tags: python, html, django, svelte, sveltekit

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="icon" href="/static/icons/tabIcon.svg" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/posty.css" />

    <meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="" />
    <link
      rel="modulepreload"
      href="/static/_app/immutable/start-6f351e07.js"
    />
    <link
      rel="modulepreload"
      href="/static/_app/immutable/chunks/index-d9a79891.js"
    />
    <link
      rel="modulepreload"
      href="/static/_app/immutable/chunks/index-d827f58a.js"
    />
    <link
      rel="modulepreload"
      href="/static/_app/immutable/chunks/singletons-eca981c1.js"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <script type="module" data-sveltekit-hydrate="45h" crossorigin>
        import {
          set_public_env,
          start,
        } from "/static/_app/immutable/start-6f351e07.js";

        set_public_env({});

        start({
          target: document.querySelector('[data-sveltekit-hydrate="45h"]')
            .parentNode,
          paths: { base: "", assets: "/static/" },
          session: {},
          route: true,
          spa: true,
          trailing_slash: "never",
          hydrate: null,
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### svelte.config.js

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            assets: 'build/assets',
            out: 'dist',
            fallback: 'index.html',
            precompress: false
        })
    }
};

export default config;
```

### settings.py

```
# ...
DEBUG = True

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/assets')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
# ...
```

#### Errors

```
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/_app/immutable/pages/__layout.svelte-bd484656.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/_app/immutable/assets/__layout-ce6f71c3.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/_app/immutable/chunks/index-d9a79891.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
... 9+ more errors
```

### Desc

Even using `python manage.py runserver --nostatic --insecure` (using whitenoise) still causes this error, and after building the production version I have to change all of the urls in `index.html` to start with `/static/` or else no files would be found, is there any way to fix or automate during deployment, and is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do that in Django is to load static in the beginning

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and use the static template tag to build the URL for the given relative path using the configured [`STATICFILES_STORAGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#staticfiles-storage), like

```
<link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

This way if you change the static URL you won't have to change in multiple places of the template. [Read more about it here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files).

For reference, inside the script tags one can use [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script). [Read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65286399/7109869).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Goncalos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73545256/3155240), unless, something has changed during my few years of being inactive in Javascript, I don't believe you can load js files with the `<link>` tag.

so tags like these (where you are trying to load Javascript files):

```
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/static/_app/immutable/chunks/singletons-eca981c1.js"/>
```

need to be changed to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/_app/immutable/chunks/singletons-eca981c1.js"><script/>
```

I've had this same error as well. A few times where I was trying to load javascript in `<link>` and a few times where I couldn't load anything - images, scripts, css, etc.

Comment: It is possible to use in specific contexts. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51105967/7109869).

Comment: Oh, wow. I had not a clue - thank you!